# Why is my toast application not compiling

Tags: java, android

```
    package com.example.toast;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import static android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

     public void fun(View v) {
     Toast t;
     t = Toast.makeText( context:this, resid: "Welcome to Android", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
     t.show();
    }
```

The words "conext" and "resid" are highlighted in red so I'm not sure what is going on. The code will not compile and I'm struggling to understand why. I am following the instructions word for word from the book.

I am getting this error:
AAPT: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

Comment: Perhaps in the book `context` and `resid` are formatted differently from `this` and `"Welcome to Android` to let you know that ones are parameter names and ones are actual values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just Type**

```
 Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Welcome to Android", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Reason For not showing**
you were typing out "context:" and "resid" but in fact, you only need the 3 parameters

1. Context = **MainActivity.this** in your case
2. Test to show = your custom text
3. Duration of Toast = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT/Toast.LENGTH_LONG depending upon your situation.

Comment: `this` is not a valid parameter to fun

Comment: BTW why do you need seperate function just for toast ?

Comment: remove Parameter "View v" from function fun(); then call it in main activity like fun();

Comment: If it's bound to an onClick function, needs to be it's own method with a View parameter

Comment: So you are binding the function fun() in XML?

Comment: if you have bound the method fun() in xml then there is no need to call it in onCreate or anywhere. just correct the parameters in Toast

Comment: I've also updated my answer, and sorry for the wrong answer :)

Comment: Thanks it compiles, I put "fun" in activity_main.xml as android:onClick="fun" but I'm not sure why I'm not seeing a button on the emulator even though I defined everything for the button in activity_main

Comment: it might be due to, You have not set constraints of the button

Comment: also please mark the question as answered, to close the question :)

Answer (score 3):

Were you watching a video  or image and copied the code?

The `context:` and `resid:` are IDE hints, not actual text in the method call.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove context: and resid: from the arguments. Those are syntax errors in Java, so the code won't compile.

```
package com.example.toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  public void fun(View v) {
     Toast t;
     t = Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome to Android", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
     t.show();
  }
}
```